# PHP でインスタンス自身を示す $this について

Tags: php

ある参考書籍(「詳細PHP7 + MySQL入門ノート」p220)
に以下のように書いてあります。<参考書籍>内の【】でくくってある部分

//【$nameは同名のローカル変数を探すため】値はnullです。

の部分ですが、この場合「ローカル変数」の「ローカル」とは

①hello()以下の{}で囲まれたスコープの範囲内ということでしょうか？

②それとも下記の<記述>内にある class OurList以下の{}で囲まれたクラスの定義内という意味でしょうか？

初学者でローカル変数という用語に混乱しています。①、②どちらが正しいのでしょうか？ それともこれ以外の範囲に該当するのですか？ この書籍に書かれているローカル変数という用語が出てきた場合、その範囲について初心者でもわかるように解説してください。
宜しくお願い致します。

＜参考書籍＞

×間違ったコード

---

```
public function hello(){
echo "こんにちは、{$name}さん！";
}
```

---

●$this-> プロパティ名
上記のコードは間違っています。$nameではプロパティ $nameにアクセスできません。【$nameは同名のローカル変数を探すため】値はnullです。
プロパティ $nameにアクセスするには、インスタンス自身を指し示す$thisを使って「$this->name」のように記述しなくてはなりません。

〇正しいコード

---

```
public function hello(){
echo "こんにちは、{$this->name}さん！";
}
```

---

---

＜記述＞

```
<?php
class OurList{
public $name;
public $age;

public function hello(){
echo "こんにちは、{$this->name}さん！";

}
public function age(){
echo "{$this->name}さんは今年{$this->age}歳です。";
}
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset ="utf-8">
<title>クラス名簿</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>
<?php
$rika = new OurList();
$taichi = new OurList();

$rika->name = "里佳子";
$rika->age = 21;

$taichi ->name = "泰一朗";
$taichi ->age = 19;


print_r($rika);
print_r($taichi);

$rika->hello();
echo "<br>";
$taichi->hello();
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";

$rika->age();
echo "<br>";
$taichi->age();
?>
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

---

＜表示結果＞

```
OurList Object
(
[name] => 里佳子
[age] => 21
)
OurList Object
(
[name] => 泰一朗
[age] => 19
)
こんにちは、里佳子さん！
こんにちは、泰一朗さん！

里佳子さんは今年21歳です。
泰一朗さんは今年19歳です。
```

Answer (score 1):

回答は

> ①hello()以下の{}で囲まれたスコープの範囲内

「ローカル」とは特定の[変数のスコープ](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/language.variables.scope.php)の範囲を示し、
「ローカル変数」といったら特定の変数のスコープの範囲の中にある変数を指します。

例えば以下のような関数があった場合、

```
<?php
$a = "Hello";             // A
function HelloWorld($a) { // B
  $a = "World";           // C
  echo $a;                // D
}
HelloWorld($a);           // E
```

- Aの$aの変数と同列のスコープの$aはEになります。
- Bの$aの変数と同列のスコープの$aはC,Dになります。

関数の中の変数はスコープが違うことがわかると思います。

混乱するのは「変数」と「クラスの[プロパティ](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/language.oop5.properties.php)」を同列に扱ってしまっているからだと思います。
よく似た書き方をしますが性質は全く異なるものです。
それぞれ違いものという認識をもっていくとよいでしょう。

Answer (score 1):

まず、

```
class OurList {
    public $name;
    public $age;
    ：
    ：
}
```

として、メンバ変数「$name」が定義されていますが、クラスの中で、この変数にアクセス（値を参照したり、代入したりする）には「**$this->name**」と書く必要があります。**$this はクラス自身**を指しています。

そのため、関数の中で $this->name の値を使いたいのであれば、

```
public function hello() {
    echo "こんにちは、{$name}さん！";
}
```

のように「**$name**」と書いてしまうのは間違い、ということです。

前述のメンバ変数にも $name があるので、少し分かりにくいと思いますが（まぁ、そこを狙った問題なんでしょうけど）、この**関数の中の $name は、関数の中でしか使用できません**。また、**関数の中の $name は、ここで初めて登場している（まだ値が代入されていない）ため null である**、ということです。

変数がどこで使用できるのかは、**スコープ**によって決まります。スコープについては、すでにほかの方が回答されていますので割愛しますが、**すべてのスコープで使えるグローバル変数**に対して、**限られたスコープでのみ使えるのがローカル変数**です。
（$this->name も、スコープはクラスの中にしかありませんので、これもローカル変数です）

ということで、ご質問の「この場合「ローカル変数」の「ローカル」とは①ということでしょうか？②という意味でしょうか？」への**回答としては、① ということになります**ね。

分かりにくかったらすみません！